# How to force someone to put a time field hh:mm in a textfield?

Tags: ios, datetime, uitextfield

I have a text field in which you must enter a time. The format is `hh:mm` type `23:40`. How to I can bind to and enter that field, or in case you can not, as I read put `21.30` or `21.30` as `21:30`

Comment: You could use the UITextField Delegate and put the Numeric KeyBoard, but as suggested by Fogmeister, an UIDatePicker seems the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do it this way at all.

If you want a HH:MM time entry in a `UITextField` then use a `UIDatePicker` as the input type.

That way they can select a time from the picker and you only get a valid entry.

Create a `UIDatePicker` and set it as the `inputView` of the `UITextField`. This stops the keyboard presenting.

Now in the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldDidBecomeFirstResponder` you can present the `datePicker`. Then in the date picker methods when the time is changed set the text programatically in the textfield.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :-) Although I have not understood very well what to do, I'm new to the pickers :( .. Could you give me an example, please?Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use `UITextField` to do this, When keyboard appear, using keyboard notification, set `textField.inputView as UIDatePicekr`. And use `HH:MM` format for 24 hours as like your case `21.30`. See [this link](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time) for Date format

Comment: You could explain it with a small example? Because I am new to the pickers and I'm a little lost ..Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

Use a "mask" to force a particular type of input out of the users